# Find exact match in haystack but only when text is not part of larger string of chars

Tags: javascript, jquery

My google-fu has failed me here, because I'm not sure how to search for an answer without getting generic results for finding a string needle in a haystack in javascript. If this is a duplicate question, just let me know and I'll close this one out.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm currently searching through text using indexOf() in javascript to find any occurrence of a user's username that starts with the @ char. indexOf is working well enough in most cases for this, but it's failing when a user has a name that is also part of another user's name.

For instance, using indexOf(), I current get matches for a username  "RandomDonkey" when there is text directed at "@RandomDonkeyKong" or "@RandomDonkeyFarmer".

**What I'm looking for**

I'd like to find the most efficient way to ensure that messages containing (for example) "@RandomDonkeyFarmer" don't cause alerts for the user "RandomDonkey", as only an exact match with no extra chars included with the username for "@RandomDonkey" should be cause for an alert.

**What I've considered**

I'm no good at writing regex, so I've considered it a possible solution but am not sure how to write it.

I've also considered looking for the match, and the further checking that there are no characters other than a space after the last character (assuming that the username doesn't end the string).

Is there a better way to go about this, or would one of those two solutions be the most efficient?

**The code I'm currently using and some examples that should pass / fail**

```
var username = 'RandomDonkey';

if(message.toLowerCase().indexOf('@' + username.toLowerCase()) != -1){
   alert('this is a direct message');
}//if direct message
else{
    alert('this is NOT a direct message');
}
```

Some messages that should pass:

```
message = "Hey @randomdonkey what's going on?";
message = "@RandomDonkey what are you up to";
message = "These are silly examples @RandomDonkey";
```

Some messages that should fail:

```
message = "@RandomDonkeyKong is not a match for RandomDonkey";
message = "I'm messaging @RandomDonkeyFarmer";
```

Currently all of these examples pass because of the way that indexOf() works, which is why I'm looking for another method.

Comment: You are searching through a single text string, or is it an array of string? Let's see some code.

Comment: @Malk It's just a single text string. The code is currently just a generic use of the indexOf() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe regex is indeed the answer. This should work for most cases:

```
var username = "RandomDonkey"
var text = "hey @RandomDonkey are you something something etc."

var re=new RegExp("@"+username+"\b", "i")
if (re.test(text)) {
    alert(username);
}
```

This works when usernames can only have word characters in them (so A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and the underscore character _)

To allow usernames with dashes so that this doesn't break, use this in place of `"\b"` in the regex: `"([^\\w\\-]|$)"`

So the regex defining line becomes: `var re=new RegExp("@"+username+"([^\\w\\-]|$)", "i")`

It looks for a character which **doesn't** match a word character or a dash, so anything passwords shouldn't contain, or the end of the string.

The only issues that might arise are if people have special regex chars in their usernames, which should be easily preventable by just prohibiting usernames that don't match `^[\w\-]+$` (one or more letters, numbers, dashes and underscores and nothing more)

Comment: How would I go about allowing a dash in the user names? The username system allows letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores. This looks like it's pretty much there, would I just need to sanitize the usernames for use in the regex somehow?

Comment: Made a change to the solution, should work with dashes in usernames now.

Comment: It's getting there. The only thing not working right now is if the username is the last thing (or only thing) in the string it fails. And thank you so much for taking the time to help me out here.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Forgot to add checks for that. Just a sec. And don't worry, I don't have much to do anyway, so I'm happy to help.

Comment: "[^\w\-|$]" and "\[\w\-|$]" still seem to be having trouble when the username is the only thing in the string or at the end.

Comment: OK. Let's try that again. Should work with this version.

Comment: Actually, that still gives me true when the username is a substring of a longer username.

Comment: Damn it, I missed one caret in the longer line. If you were copying it from that one, that should explain why it did what it did.

Comment: "([^\w\-]|$)" this one still accepts longer versions of the username the way. Thanks again for all your help though.

Comment: Gah - finally realized why it wasn't working. The regex is given inside a string, so the backslashes need to be escaped in the string so they go to the regex as actual backslashes.